# Most efficient datastructure to represent a NxN board

Tags: java, performance, complexity-theory

I was wondering if you guys could point me towards some more efficient datastructures in which I can represent a NxN puzzle board.

At this point, it's still a basic 2 dimensional matrix (`int[][]`). Although it serves its purpose, I feel it lacks on the whole performance aspect.

The puzzle itself is called "the sliding problem", e.g. 8puzzle, 15puzzle,..

an 8 puzzle looks like this:

```
  1 3         1 2 3
4 2 5   --->  4 5 6
7 8 6         7 8
```

One operation I am using is O(n^4), I'd like to find a "solution" for this.
This operation tries to find, for every board entry, the coordinates of the value that *should* be there. (distance heuristics)

```
value = 1;
for(int i = 0; i <puzzle.length; i++)
   for(int j = 0; j < puzzle[0].length; j++)
      getPosition(value++)
```

with getPosition also using 2 for loops:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < puzzle.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < puzzle[0].length; j++) 
            if(puzzle[i][j]==value)
                return new int[]{i,j};
```

I was thinking of using a HashMap, using `new int[]{x_coord, y_coord}` as key for each entry.

Looking forward to your suggestions, thanks in advance!

Comment: We don't know, because we don't know which game you are playing and which operations are you invoking (and how they are implemented). We need some more information.

Comment: *"Some operations are O(n^4) for example."* -- Well what operations are you trying to perform?

Comment: Well, if you can represent your co-ordinates as a single integer (which you can), you can't get much more efficient than an array.  Or you can create a 2D array.  There are ways to do this dynamically that are very efficient.

Comment: The hashmap may cause loss of data locality in the memory, slowing down your accesses - depending on how you access the elements. It won't lower any complexity as the access time remains O(1)

Comment: @Slanec you are totally right, I tried updating with some additional information

Comment: @arshajii It was indeed poorly asked, I updated the question with some additional information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to optimize the data structure in terms of *complexity* (assuming that you have boards of size 100x100 or so, where this is really worth thinking about) you first have to make clear *which* operations will be executed most frequently.

One operations that is probably required frequently in such a puzzle is

> Given coordinates (r,c) : Which number is at these coordinates?

The array is already perfectly suited for this. One could consider using an 1D array to enforce more data locality, but detailed benchmarks would be necessary to justify this decision.

You mentioned another operation:

*"This operation tries to find, for every board entry, the coordinates of the value that should be there"*

This sounds a bit unusual, because I can't imagine what you might need this for - except, maybe, for sort of "distance measure". However, the core of this operation can be formulated as

> Given a number x: Which are the coordinates (r,c) of this number?

This could again be solved by arrays, namely two arrays

```
int rows[] = new int[totalSize];
int cols[] = new int[totalSize];
```

So given the board from your example:

```
  1 3
4 2 5
7 8 6
```

These arrays could contain

```
rows = { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2 }
cols = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1 }
```

That is, the coordinates of `5` are currently `(rows[5], columns[5]) = (1,2)`

Of course, you will have to update this data structure for every move that you apply to the board. This implies a constant (!) overhead for each move. But for larger boards, this will quickly pay out, because finding the coordinates of a certain value now only has O(1), in contrast to O(n²) as before.

Comment: The operation is indeed for distance heuristics. Thanks for your answer, it totally makes sense!